# File upload destinationpath is not uploading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

> Problem is my Storage is not working. It's not uploading my file into destinationPath. When i dd my file path it not taking destination.

**Controller@store**

```php
$destinationPath = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$bank.'/'.$username.'/'.$date.'/';        
foreach ($files as $file) {
   $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
   Storage::put($destinationPath.$filename.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(),file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
}
```

**Controller@show**

```php
$directory = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$bank->$bank.'/'.$bank->username.'/'.$bank->date.'/';
$files = Storage::files($directory);
dd($files);
return view('banks.show', ['bank'=>$bank])->with(array('files' => $files));
```

**Config/app**

```php
'fileDestinationPath' => 'uploads',
'allowedFileTypes' => 'jpg,jpeg,bmp,png',
'maxFileSize' => 1000000*2,
```

**Config/filesystems**

```php
public' => [
 'driver' => 'local',
 'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
 'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
 'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Comment: is probably not the answer but you got a typo in filesystems example `public'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App\Filesystems.php

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => resource_path('app');
],
```